# how to create event mapper in spartacus

Tags: google-tag-manager, spartacus-storefront, gwt-eventservice

In spartacus I need to create one event mapper service for gtm event tracking from starting

I try simple doc of spartacus eventservice but not understanding anyhting where to start...
simply make one custom button and call event on that and track via gtm